# White borders around text with theme org-beautify-theme

Tags: themes, font-lock

I'm using these themes in my init file (it's literally all that is in my init file):

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
(load-theme 'org-beautify-theme t) 
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
```

The result looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nncig.png

How do I get rid of these white borders? I think these borders are coming from the default white background color (if I disable the zenburn theme, the border blends into the white background).

I'm on Windows 7, Emacs version is 24.5.1.

By the way, it's really hard coming up with a tag if you don't have enough reputation to create new ones and you're left with no options because any other tag wouldn't make sense in this context... I tried 'theme', 'color', but they don't exist and so I had to put in some unrelated but existing tag like 'package' since it doesn't let me post the question without zero tags (which makes sense)...

Comment: No need to come up with a tag, `themes` is already a thing :P

Comment: Sorry about the bars.  It's a bit of a hack to give some extra spacing around the org-mode titles and subtitles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by [the comment at the top](https://github.com/jonnay/emagicians-starter-kit/blob/master/themes/org-beautify-theme.el#L22-L24), it should be sufficient to load zenburn first, then org-beautify.

Comment: Aww man, I was so sure I've tried this already, but apparently, it was samething else I tried. It worked, thanks a ton, wasamasa!